# Is there a way using htaccess to add a virtual directory in URI?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have my wordpress installed on **www.site.com/blog/** but i would like to add language codes in front of the blog directory (**www.site.com/us/blog/**, **www.site.com/es/blog/** and so on). Is there a way achiving this? I need to keep those virtual directories inside URI so when visiting **www.site.com/us/blog** i want to show **www.site.com/us/blog** in the address bar.

This is my .htaccess file from www.site.com/blog/ directory.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/blog/$ blog/?language=$1
```

it's been a while since i've written .htaccess, let me know how this works out.

edit: here's a helpful tutorial on how it works :)
https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/(.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L]
```

It checks for any 2 letter prefix at the start of the URL, followed by anything else, then treats that as a request for the bit after, so `/us/blog` will be treated as a request for `/blog`, just as `/es/page/123` would be treated as a request for `/page/123`. So long as a visitor goes to the prefixed URL, the address won't be redirected.

If you want to be more specific about what language prefixes to use, do this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(es|fr|us)/(.*)$ /$2 [QSA,L]
```

Making sure you add the ones you want between the first set of parantheses (and separated by pipes (`|`) as shown above.

Comment: The answer by @hazonko above is perhaps better as he is allowing for you to get a HTTP GET parameter containing the language requested (if you need it).

Comment: I have edited my question, using your second method, the URI is correct in the address bar but wordpress redirect to a 404 page. Same thing goes for @Hazonko . Thanks.

Comment: Try removing `L` where it says `[QSA,L]` (and the comma). Make sure it's above the main wordpress RewriteRule you may already have (but after `RewriteEngine on`. `L` means 'stop reading rules here, but you probably want it to continue on and do the normal wordpress rewrite as well.